# Ignore SSL Verifications in DevTools when reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl-certificate

I am trying to do a remote reindexing from an elastic cluster to another (both are in a closed network).
I tried to do it from the DevTools console but stumbled upon the following error :

> "error" : {
> "root_cause" : [
> {
> "type" : "s_s_l_handshake_exception",
> "reason" : "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target"

Our SSL certificates are not working and we usually bypass them by using `verify_certs=False` when working with Python or `-k` when curling.

Do you know if there is any similar way to do for the DevTools console ? Couldn't find any.
I guess I could disable all SSL and security parameters for the duration of the reindexing or just fix the SSL certificates (I wish I could) :')
but I'd like to find an easier/less time consuming way and more generally just know if this is possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

You can't directly do it from DevTools but what you can do is add `reindex.ssl.verification_mode` to `none` in elasticsearch.yml in order to bypass any type of control **for the reindex API**.

I found this information in [this part of the Reindex API Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docs-reindex.html#reindex-ssl). I guess it should work the same for other API functions.